# Namespace prefix 'm2' is not defined

Tags: c#, visual-c++, bluetooth

Hey im trying to do Universal Windows App that scan all bluetooth devices. So i started with this line of code to scan:

```
var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));

foreach (var device in devices)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(device);
}
```

But this isn't working so i want to add DeviceCapability to my  form.

```
  <Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
  <m2:Device Id="any">
    <m2:Function Type="name.serialPort"/>
  </m2:Device>
</m2:DeviceCapability>
```

But Visual Studio is saying that Namespace prefix 'm2' is not defined.

Comment: Did you define `m2`? If so, where?

Comment: ok i define m2 by adding   xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest"
and "Namespace prefix 'm2' is not defined" is gone,
but app still not working. listBox is empty

Comment: Then `FindAllAsync` is either broken, or there is nothing to find. Check that function, and return value before it is returned and see why its returning an empty collection

Answer (score 1):

I tried to remove the M2 and it stopped giving me errors. Specifically my code now looks like:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
      <Device Id="any">
        <!-- Used by the Microsoft Band SDK -->
        <Function Type="serviceId:A502CA9A-2BA5-413C-A4E0-13804E47B38F" />
        <!-- Used by the Microsoft Band SDK -->
        <Function Type="serviceId:C742E1A2-6320-5ABC-9643-D206C677E580" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```